# I want to send the data from a request form to a database in the MySQL workbench from a javascript file in a ReactJs project, but I have no idea how

Tags: mysql, reactjs, database, mysql-workbench, workbench

I want to send the data from a request form to a database in the MySQL workbench from a javascript file in a ReactJs project, but I have no idea how.

```
<div className='formsection'>
  <form action="index.php" method='post' className='form'>
   <input type="text" placeholder='Name*'/>
    <br />
    <input type="email" placeholder='E-Mail*' />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder='Nachricht*' />
    <br />
     <input type="checkbox" />
     <br />
    <input type="submit" value={'Absenden'} />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have an API endpoint that is connected to your MySQL database and can perform required tasks.

Next, you have to decide whether you will do it with a 3rd party solution like  [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) or write your own approaches to deal with the form. Then if you prefer to do it by yourself, you have to choose whether to use `axios`, plain `fetch`, or the other ways to perform `xhr` to that endpoint.

You can read [this](https://mattboldt.com/2020/05/02/formdata-with-react-hooks-and-fetch/) or any other tutorials by googling with keyword `react post form data to api`.

A minimal example can be like this:
Create a user state

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState();
```

then change your form become:

```html
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  ...
</form>
```

then add `onChange` handler in input tag to update the user state on every input change.

```html
   <input
      ...
      onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, key: e.target.value })}
   />
```

Then create an onSubmit react callback method where we prevent the default nature of form submit and post the user state as body to the API endpoint. We have to use `useCallback` to make sure the user state that posted to the endpoint is the latest user state value.

```js
  const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("/api/user", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
  },[user]);
```

And the minimal code will be like this:

```js
export default function UserForm() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("/api/user", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ user }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }).then((res) => console.log(res.json()));
  },[user]);

  return (
    <div className="formsection">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="user[name]"
          placeholder="Name*"
          onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="email"
          name="user[email]"
          placeholder="E-Mail*"
          onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, email: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="user[news]"
          placeholder="Nachricht*"
          onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, news: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="user[jahresurlaub]"
          onChange={(e) => setUser({ ...user, jahresurlaub: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="Absenden" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```